# Adding toolbox items for Facebook SDK v4

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Anybody know how to add the facebook v4 toolbox items? I tried adding facebook.dll and facebook.web.dll, but VS 2010 is telling me it couldn't find any toolbox items in them.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no toolkbox items in the Facebook C# SDK (http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com). The Facebook C# SDK is not a new version of the old Facebook Developer Toolkit, it is a completely seperate SDK that is compatible with the new OAuth and Graph API. The old Facebook Developer Toolkit has been depreciated. If you would like us to consider adding some please file an issue on codplex describing what sort of controls you are looking for. NOTE: I am the developer of the Facebook C# SDK.

Comment: what are you saying ? I have added Facebook controls such as FacebookService , Profile etc . myself.